# converting a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, import-from-excel

I have an excel sheet which contains date.

With the following I convert them to datetime objects:

```
def excel_time_to_string(xltimeinput):
        try:
            retVal = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(xltimeinput, wb.datemode)
        except ValueError:
            print('You passed in an argument in that can not be translated to a datetime.')
            print('Will return original value and carry on')
            retVal = xltimeinput
        return retVal
```

I define the columns which contain dates and use that def on these cells:

```
date_cols = [16, 18, 29, 42, 43]

    headerrow = wb.sheet_by_index(0).row_values(0)
    wr.writerow(headerrow)

    for rownum in xrange(1,wb.sheet_by_index(0).nrows):
        # Get the cell values and then convert the relevant ones before writing
        cell_values = wb.sheet_by_index(0).row_values(rownum)
        for col in date_cols:
            cell_values[col] = excel_time_to_string(cell_values[col])
        wr.writerow(cell_values)
```

so far so good, I get the correct object written in my csv: 
    2008-09-30 00:00:00

BUT, I need it in a different format: `%d.%m.%Y`

Am I right in my thinking that I have to do that "conversion" in the for loop instead of in the def?

Comment: So you have a datetime object and you need '%d.%m.%Y'? `datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with xlrd, but from what I can tell, the function you use (`xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime`) returns a python `datetime.datetime` object.

datetime.datetime objects have a specific format (therefore, `retVal` has a specific format), but you can change it using the `datetime.strftime()` method.

```
>>>import datetime
>>>x = datetime.today()
>>>print(x)
2015-02-26 11:31:31.432000
>>>x.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
'26.02.2015'
```

You can do this conversion directy on retVal in your function, e.g.

```
retVal = retVal.strftime('desired format')
```

Read more here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior